# Bootstrap give DIV priority

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and loving it. However, I have a slight problem I am not sure how to solve. To better explain it, I have drawn up a simple layout of the website.

This is how the site looks on a regular desktop monitor
[image]

This is how the site looks on a mobile phone (iPhone 5S)

[image]

I want everything to stay as it is EXCEPT on the mobile version layout, I want the image to come first before anything else (AkA be at the top). However, any change I make seems to mess things up on a regular desktop monitor. Is there some way to prioritize div's or something along that line? I also think it is kind of random the the image on the mobile layout comes after the text box, but I guess that is due to my code.

My code is below.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row item">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <h1>Test Tile!</h1>
                <p id="test">Text Text Text</p>
                <form  id="newsletter" action="" method="POST" class="form-inline" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                    <input type="EMAIL" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" id="EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
                    </br>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <img src="img/product_image.png" class="img-responsive main" alt="product image" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the div with the img first in your markup and add the .col-md-push-7 css class to it. It should show like you want.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your markup.

If you have `<div />` first and then the `<img />` then of course the `<img />` will always render **after** the `<div />`.

So what you need to do is swap around on your markup so the `<img />` comes first and then in your desktop specific [css](/questions/tagged/css) you'll have to either `float` or `position` the `<div />` and `<img />` to display as you want to, and then on the mobile version it should position as you'd like it to automatically.